# Limit of length of RSA signing message

Tags: objective-c, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I'm creating a signature, and having a trouble with the length of message to sign. By following the coding guide line from Apple iOS (http://apple.co/2ucaOTB), the following code is working for any message shorter than 223 length, not working for more than 222. Can you tell me why it is strictly bounded at 222?

```
NSString *dataToSign = @"eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IkFTLVVXUC1DZXJ0LTAxIiwieDVIjoiSmpBZHB3TGt4YVNvWWF0Z2NnaElpZlJ4c3A0In0śhgrphgrpehgersfnrwuiefbgerwighberuyabfgeruykbverkhgerbiuseyJzdWIiOiI2ZjAzNGViZS101MDc4ZDBjZTI0ZjIiLCJlbfasdfdfdfdfdfdqweja";//222 chars.

NSData* data2sign = [dataToSign dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Data is %u", data2sign.length);// %u will be 222.

SecKeyAlgorithm algorithm = kSecKeyAlgorithmRSASignatureDigestPSSSHA256;

// privateKey is 2048 bits asymmetric RSA.
BOOL canSign = SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(privateKey, kSecKeyOperationTypeSign, algorithm);

if (canSign) {// It is true, and it tries to create signature.
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    signature = (NSData *)CFBridgingRelease(
            SecKeyCreateSignature(
                privateKey,
                algorithm,
                (__bridge CFDataRef)data2Sign,
                &error));

    if (!signature) {
        NSError *err = CFBridgingRelease(error);
        NSLog(@"The error is: %@", err);
    }
    NSLog(@"The signature is %@", signature);
}
```

Comment: You probably forgot to hash the message.

Comment: Artjom is right of course. What I don't get is the overhead; for RSA/PKCS#1 v1.5/SHA-256 I would expect a padding overhead of 11 + 19 bytes = 30 bytes. Of a 256 bit value that should therefore still leave 226 not 222 bytes.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The AlgorithmIdentifier is 15 bytes, plus two other tags makes 17 so far. When the payload hits 112 the outer sequence moves to a two byte length, and when it hits 128 the octet string also moves to a two byte length, so 21 bytes of overhead at high payload with { id-sha256, NULL }.  But that's still 224, not 222. Apple/IBM must have some bad/defensive math.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the need for the length encoding to have a different size; I just took the overhead of the SHA-256 header, forgetting that it would have to be altered. Let's be nice and assume defensive math :)